# Bounding the commitment min-entropy of NTRU version of BLISS

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, provable-security

I've read [[DDLL13]](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Leo-Ducas/publication/265809389_Lattice_Signatures_and_Bimodal_Gaussians/links/578cf91208ae59aa66815032/Lattice-Signatures-and-Bimodal-Gaussians.pdf) paper and want to understand how the lemma 3.4 is changed for NTRU version of BLISS.

In the naive construction of BLISS, the commitment entropy is bounded in Lemma 3.4 as below:

$$ \text{Pr}[\mathbf{A}(y = t; \; y \leftarrow D_{\sigma}^m)] = \text{Pr}[y_1 = (t - \bar{\mathbf{A}}_{y_0}); \; y \leftarrow D_{\sigma}^m] \leqslant \max_{t' \in \mathbb{Z}_{2q}} \text{Pr}[y_1 = t'; \; y_1 \leftarrow D_{\sigma}^n] \leqslant 2^{-n}. $$

The authors say the commitment entropy of the NTRU version of BLISS is bounded in the same way with a straightforward adaptation of Lemma 3.4. However, the commitment of the scheme is formed $[Ay]_d$, which means only high $d$ bits remain. So the probability is changed to that $\text{Pr}([Ay]_d = t)$. So intuitively, the upperbound of the probability is $((2d+1)^n)/2^n$ which is not small at all.

Can I get any insight for the adaptation?